# how to redirect submit button another servlet

Tags: java, forms, servlets

So I am making a registration page for a web app. However,  I cannot get the submit button to redirect to the confirmation page. The registration servlet takes in the user's information and all the confirm servlet does is just display the user's name and prints out "Welcome (user's name)" 
Here is my code: 
**register servlet**

```
package register.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Register() {
        super();
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        ArrayList<HW1User> HW1Users = new ArrayList<HW1User>();

        getServletContext().setAttribute("HW1Users", HW1Users);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String docType = "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en\">\n";

        out.println(docType);
        out.println("<html>" + "<head>" + "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">" + "<title>Register</title>"
                + "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css\">"
                + "</head>" + "<body>" + "<div class=\"container\">" + "<div class=\"jumbotron\">"
                + "<h1>Welcome to Bat!</h1>"
                + "<p>Bat! is a cloud-based note taking app that allows you to create, store, edit, and share notes that you create directly in your browser!</p>"
                + "<p>To begin, register below.</p>" + "</div>"

                + "<div class=\"panel panel-primary\">" + "<div class=\"panel-heading\">"
                + "<h3 class=\"panel-title\"> New User Registration</h3>"

                + "</div>" + "<div class=\"panel-body\">" + "<form>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">"
                + "<label for=\"name\">Full Name</label>"
                + "<input type=\"name\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"fullName\" id=\"fullName\" placeholder=\"First and Last Name\">"

                + "</div>"

                + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<label for=\"email\">Email Address</label>"
                + "<input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"email\" id=\"email\" placeholder=\"Email\">"

                + "</div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<label for=\"password1\">Password</label>"
                + "<input type=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"password1\" id=\"password1\" placeholder=\"Password\">"

                + "</div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<label for=\"password2\">Re-Enter Password</label>"
                + "<input type=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"password2\" id=\"password2\" placeholder=\"Re-Enter Your Password\">"

                + "</div>"

                + "<button type=\"submit\" value =\"Post\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Register</button>" + "</form>"
                + "</div>" + "</div> <!--  End Well -->" + "</div>" + "</body>" + "</html>");


    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        ArrayList<HW1User> HW1Users = (ArrayList<HW1User>) getServletContext().getAttribute("HW1Users");

        for (HW1User entry : HW1Users)
            if (entry.getId() == id){
                entry.fullName = request.getParameter("fullName");
                entry.email = request.getParameter("email");
                entry.password1 = request.getParameter("password1");
                entry.password2 = request.getParameter("password2");
                break;
            }

        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/Confirm");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

**confirm servlet**

```
package register.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Confirm")
public class Confirm extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HW1User entry = null;

        try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            ArrayList<HW1User> HW1Users = (ArrayList<HW1User>) getServletContext().getAttribute("HW1Users");
            for (HW1User e : HW1Users){
                if (e.getId() == id){
                    entry = e;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        finally{
            if (entry == null){
                response.sendRedirect("Register");
                return;
            }
        }


        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("   <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
        out.println("   <title>Cervantes, Albert - cs320stu100</title>");
        out.println("   <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css\">");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<div class=\"container\">");

        out.println("Welcome " + entry.getName() + " !!");


    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest to hover the [servlets] tag below your question until a black popover shows up and then click therein the "info" link.

Answer (score 0):

When you want do some action on post method, you should add `method="post"` to your `form` tag.